# Import of Mixim to Omnet++ simulation

Tags: omnet++, inet, mixim

I have imported INET latest version to Omnet++ and its working fine. And i am using SUMO as traffic simulator and Veins too.
Is that mandatory to import Mixim to run our simulations in Omnet++ ?

Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking whether you need to manually import MiXim into OMNet++ to run Veins-Simulation the answer is no. Veins is actually a fork of mixim (as one can see on the veins github page https://github.com/sommer/veins)